# Full Screen Background Image(s) + Rotating Images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to implement Full-Screen / Expandable background images; I typically use a jQuery method. EG: http://tinyurl.com/9yl4rbw

BUT! I'm trying to make it so the background image is different each time the page is visited. Not a slide show; but like the old javascript (EG: http://www.computerhope.com/j18.htm)

How could I combine the two; jQuery expandable background and on-page-refresh-new image javascript?

Anyone came across a quality plugin for this effect?

*Edit_*_*_*

I use the jQuery method as within the reference URL above; essentially below:

```
<!--Expandable BG code IE 7 +-->

  <style>

                #bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
                .bgwidth { width: 100%; }
                .bgheight { height: 100%; }

                #page-wrap { position: relative; width: 950px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;;  }

  </style> 


 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(function() {   

                        var theWindow        = $(window),
                            $bg              = $("#bg"),
                            aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

                        function resizeBg() {

                                if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
                                    $bg
                                        .removeClass()
                                        .addClass('bgheight');
                                } else {
                                    $bg
                                        .removeClass()
                                        .addClass('bgwidth');
                                }

                        }

                        theWindow.resize(function() {
                                resizeBg();
                        }).trigger("resize");

                });
        </script>


<!--Expandable BG code IE 7 +-->

<!--Full BG Call-->

<img src="Sandwichfullbg.jpg" id="bg" >


<div id="page-wrap">


<!--End Full BG Call-->
```

**I'd like to discover a simple solution to having the background change on new page visit or page refresh; ideally holding around 30 images.** EG: Refresh page > New rad Image; Refresh page > New rad Image; (x 30)

Comment: what exactly is the jQuery method you're using? how does it work?

Comment: Just edited my Q describing above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the new `background-size:cover`, for the background, and then use jQuery to randomly change this background image as per the normal method?

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/CqGwx/1/) for you, basically doing everything you need. (Keep clicking Run in jsfiddle and you'll see the background-image cycle randomly).

Be aware, background-size:cover, mainly works with newer bowers, but by using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) this can be overcome.

Install Modernizr by linking it in your header

```
<script src="http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
```

And in your HTML tag,

```
<html class="no-js">
```

Edit: As per the comments, I've made another way that has more browser support:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/36cL6/)

This time I've just made it randomly apply a class, of which this class has vendor-prefixs and fixes for ie-7/ie-8 and all the rest really. It won't look perfect in IE8, but images will fully stretch to fit the height/width of the body.

Comment: Rad! What's the support on this method; the only reason I settled for that jQuery one I referenced within past projects is because I supported at IE 7 +, ?

Comment: Your answer is misleading. Keep in mind, Modernizr doesn't actually fix older browsers, it merely detects whether or not certain features are available. What OP could do, is to use yepnope.js (bundled with standard Modernizr) and then run the javascript function only of `background-size` is not available. Of course, this is not answering the question OP asks.

Comment: Added a different method of achieving roughly the same result, with more browser support straight off the bat.

Comment: Alex, great fiddle! Thanks, man -- one small problem; once I implemented about 10 photos it loads really really slow. Any solution to optimizing load time with this solution?

Answer (score 3):

Add this code at the top of you JS. It will set the src property of the image to a random value from Sandwichfullbg0.jpg to Sandwichfullbg29.jpg (so 30 different images in total)

```
$('#bg').attr('src', 'Sandwichfullbg' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + '.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://images.alexmeub.com.s3.amazonaws.com/resize_bg.html). View the source and check it out. I use an image with a low z-index because it makes resizing easier. Also, I would optimize your background image so its not so big. It's almost a MB and it takes way too long to load. Your version doesn't resize well when the aspect ratio isn't widescreen.